# Binding SelecteItem in TabControl

Tags: c#, binding, mvvm, tabcontrol, datacontext

It is MVVM project. I have a ListBox with TabControls inside of it's items. TabItems are different for each TabControl and are binded from ViewModel:

```
                <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}"
                </TabControl >
```

Tabs are:

```
    public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs
    {   get { return tabs;  }
        set {
            tabs = value;
            value.CollectionChanged += delegate
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("Tabs");
            };

            OnPropertyChanged("Tabs"); } }
```

Tabs are filled by the following way only once:

```
                Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();

                if (details.Image != null || !String.IsNullOrEmpty(details.Summary))
                    Tabs.Add(new TabItem() { Header = "General Info", Content = new GeneralInfo() { DataContext = ItemDetails } });  ........... 6 different types
```

This is a bit info about what I have. Then I dinamically change DataContext's of this TabControls to simulate scrolling.

All info from ViewModel is binded into control, but there is a problem with TabControl. Headers are binded. but content doesnt. All headers are deselected and TabCntrol content area is empty.

I have tried to make TwoWayBinding on SelectedIndex and SelectedItem, but it doesnt help....
Seems SelectedIndex doesn't do anything that can select TabItem. 
And SelectedItem doesn't work,becuase as I think it has new reference after each changing of data context. Because TabControl.ItemsSource re-binds and new TabItems created.

Maybe someone solved same problem and knows solution?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you raise "Tabs" everytime the Collection changes? That doesn't make much sense to me. ObservableCollection already notifys about specific changes inside the collection (added, removed etc) while these fire, you tell the UI "Forget about the collection, get my new collection". If your collection completely changes, yes raise "Tabs" if not and just something inside the collection changes don't do anything, thats work that the ObservableCollection does automatically.

Comment: sure, thanks, my mistake. But it doesnt solve actual problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the my issue.
The problem was that I used controls as DataContext:
- List of TabItems
- Controls inside TabItems content
There was some processes, that I dont undrstand entire. But, idea is that while DataContext's changing, one DataContext can be assigned to 2 different TabControls. Since UI Controls cant belong to 2 parents at the same moment, so, binding that should show that controls from DataContext in content doesnt work. And doesnt throw excpetion (cause it's binding Smile | :) )

So, I remove al UI objects from DataContext, and add object models. And create UserControls that display are Views for these object models